# django - postman login failed

Tags: django, postman

use django 2.0.2 mac 10.13 postman 5.5.2

```
Web Use
def login(request):
    form = UserCreateForm
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           username = form['username'].value()
           password = form['password'].value() 
           user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
           if user is not None:
              if user.is_active:
                  login(request, user)
                  return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request , 'blog/user_create.html',{'form':form})

 Post Man Use
 def login(request):
        if request.POST:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/')
        return redirect('/')



error Log


 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 923, in to_python
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/junholee/django1/authtest/blog/views.py", line 43, in signin
    login(request, user)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 132, in login
    if _get_user_session_key(request) != user.pk or (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 61, in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 928, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'None' value must be an integer."]
```

connect 127.0.0.1:8000/login from web(Form) i succses login
but

i try
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login?username=user1&password=test123
from postman
raise excetion this(error Log)

delete COOKIE and cache after try raise excetion too

postman use POST body result this

request.session[SESSION_KEY] is None

[use JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP22v.png)

[use form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyTXQ.png)

Comment: That Url parameter will be used as a GET, not POST. So in the POSTMAN try giving the values in Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`@Sagar`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3608717/sagar) mentioned in the comment, you have to provide `data` through POSTMAN if you using a `POST` method,

Your request payload must be like this and put it in `body` section in POSTMAN:

```
{
    "username":"some_user_name",
    "password":"some secret password"
}
```

Refer to my screenshot for more details:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: try this but faild , upload screenshot

Comment: any traceback ?

Comment: At the end of the post     use JSON

Comment: post your tranceback

Comment: solved . postman does not have session ID so use Postman Interceptor .  login succes